Bounding the number of fully connected vertex subsets of a graph
I have a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices with edge density $p$. I am most interested in $p=O(1)$ but I would also appreciate ideas for the sparse case. My goal is to bound the number of subsets $A,B\subseteq V(G)$ with $e(A,B)=|A||B|$.
I am fine with posing the additional assumption that $G$ is quasirandom. In this case, we immediately arrive at a bound of $2^{n+o(n)}$, but we should be able to significantly improve this. For a $G(n,p)$ random graph, I believe it is possible to get much better asymptotics.
Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Looking at the complement, you would like to count bi-independent sets in sparse graphs (i.e. $o(n^2)$ edges) if I understand correctly?
Perhaps Section 2.2 from this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2404.01057 might help you, depending on the specific graph you are looking at.

This is what I want in the case of regular graphs. Know that I know the terminology, I have some reading to do. Thank you!

You're welcome! It might be good to know that the proofs are often easily adapted to non-regular graphs, but are much easier to state for regular ones. Imposing some quasirandomness might be sufficient to replicate the proof techniques for most of these kind of bounds, depending of course on what kind of graph you start out with.
